# How to Customise the angular material date-picker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using the material design date picker

```
<md-content flex class="padding-top-0 padding-bottom-0" layout="row">
                <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Start date" flex ng-click="ctrl.openCalendarPane($event)"></md-datepicker>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Due date" flex></md-datepicker>
            </md-content>
```

and its shows the UI like this
[image]

I want to remove the calendar icon and include the ng-click functionality in the input box.

How to bind the runtime event with the input box?

**css**

```
<style>
 .inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-button {
    width: 36px; }
    .inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-input-container {
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
    .md-datepicker-input-container{
    display:block;
    }
    .md-datepicker-input[placeholder]{
        color=red;
    }

    .padding-top-0{
    padding-top:0px;}

    .padding-bottom-0{
    padding-bottom:0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I also would be interested how to split date field and picker here. Thx.

Comment: Just inspect the elements that the Browser output and then map it on your css file changing it using !important

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the function for manipulate event and hide image of calendar as:

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.initDatepicker = function(){
        angular.element(".md-datepicker-button").each(function(){
            var el = this;
            var ip = angular.element(el).parent().find("input").bind('click', function(e){
                angular.element(el).click();
            });
            angular.element(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
    };
});
```

```css
.inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-button {
  width: 36px;
}
.inputdemoBasicUsage .md-datepicker-input-container {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.md-datepicker-input-container {
  display: block;
}
.md-datepicker-input[placeholder] {
  color:red;
}
.padding-top-0 {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.padding-bottom-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.2/angular-material.min.css">

<div ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="initDatepicker();">
    <md-content flex class="padding-top-0 padding-bottom-0" layout="row">
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate1" md-placeholder="Start date" flex ng-click="ctrl.openCalendarPane($event)"></md-datepicker>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate2" md-placeholder="Due date" flex></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm new to css and angular can you please explain me or give some link so that i understand how is that ip is working..and great solution it was really helpfull

Comment: @santhosh, i not understand you question. You can read the documentation of angular or material: http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/

Comment: i have not understood that initialization to the variable ip.

Answer (score 4):

using the above anwser, I changed this lines to display better:

```
.md-datepicker-input-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to write my own styles like you in my component but it is not effecting in output, where i have to write my own styles to get effected, now am writing in my.component.css.

Answer (score 3):

Additional to @EmirMarques answer, I wanted to make the input field read only. so i added this code. Here user can't edit the date input field. so its

### Better One

```
$scope.initDatepicker = function(){
        angular.element(".md-datepicker-button").each(function(){
            var el = this;
            var ip = angular.element(el).parent().find("input").bind('click', function(e){
                angular.element(el).click();
            });
            angular.element(el).parent().find("input").prop('readonly', true);
            angular.element(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });
};
```

And this CSS made the look better

```
.md-datepicker-input-container {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not using AngularJs MD functionality?

- md-hide-icons="all|triangle|calendar": to hide all/triangle or calendar buttons;
- And md-open-on-focus to open datepicker on input box click.

```html
<md-content flex class="padding-top-0 padding-bottom-0" layout="row">
                <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Start date" flex md-hide-icons="calendar" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
                <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Due date" flex md-hide-icons="calendar" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
            </md-content>
```